# Optional property on the first element of an array but required on the others

Tags: typescript

I would like to define an interface for an array of objects, where all of the objects should have the same structure, with the exception that the first element has one of the properties as optional.

An example of the data stored in the array would look like the following:

```
const array: Item[] = [{
  value: 'Value1'
},
{
  label: 'Label2',
  value: 'Value2'
},
{
  label: 'Label3',
  value: 'Value3'
},
{
  label: 'Label4',
  value: 'Value4'
}];
```

My current interface looks like the following:

```
interface Item {
  label?: string;
  value: string;
}
```

This means that the `label` property is optional on all elements of the array, while I want it to be optional on the first one, but mandatory on the rest.

Comment: Presumably you're looking for `[Item, ...Required<Item>[]]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGQ4W)?  If so then I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example code to show an unsatisfied use case.

Comment: @jcalz Your answer is very similar to the one that was posted (but looks a bit nicer as there is no need to define two interfaces) and it does correspond to what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (Typescript 4.0+) like so:

```
interface First {
    label?: string;
    value: string;
}

interface Item {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}

type Items = [First, ...Item[]];

const array: Items = [
    {
        value: 'Value1',
    },
    {
        label: 'Label2',
        value: 'Value2',
    },
    {
        label: 'Label3',
        value: 'Value3',
    },
    {
        label: 'Label4',
        value: 'Value4',
    },
];
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! awesome answer

Comment: Does this meet the presumable [use case](https://tsplay.dev/mAvrRW) where the `label` is allowed on the first element?

Comment: Nope, I will fix that in the answer :), thanks for the notice.